# canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 returns 'yes' on iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, video, camera, preset

I want to check if the iPhone the user has supports full HD video capturing. I found out, that I should ask the AV session, if

```
avSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    [avSession beginConfiguration];
    if ([avSession canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080]) {
        avSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080;
        NSLog(@"FULLHD");
    } else {
        avSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720;
        NSLog(@"HDREADY");
    }
    [avSession commitConfiguration];
```

This works fine on iPhone 5 (which indeed supports full HD capturing), but on iPhone 4 tries too to set the preset, but clearly fails. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Matthias

Comment: same problem here. Doing this:     if([captureSession canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080] == YES ) {
        [captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080];
    } else {
        [captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto];
    } works on my iPhone 5 but when run on my iPhone 4 it tries to set it to 1929X1080 and the session shows nothing. If I force the Photo preset then it works on the iPhone 4. Anybody?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Did you call canSetSettingPreset after add an input to the capture session?

```
[captureSession addInput:captureInput]; // <--- you should add an input before canSetSessionPreset
[captureSession addOutput:captureOutput];


if( [captureSession canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720] == YES ) {
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetiFrame1280x720;
} else {
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the solution. Can't vote up for now, to less reputation :(

Comment: @user2228816 It's ok that my answer helped you :) Have a good day.

Comment: Do you consider accepting this answer @user2228816 ? It helps to build the community. :)